# error-channel is not working in splitter / aggregator (asynchronous call)

Tags: spring, asynchronous, error-handling, spring-integration, aggregate

I created an application that calls a gateway asynchronously using Splitter / Aggregator. In my concfiguration file, I invoke the process via InvestmentMessagingGateway that proceeds on calling the splitter. Every splitted message calls a service activator in parallel and pass it inn aggregator.
I placed an error channel in the InvestmentMessagingGateway  and transform every failed message to pass to the aggregator as well.

I collect every successful and failed message in aggregator as a compilation for the response.
But when I tried to place an exception in one or more of the messages, I get an error in my aggregator,

Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="......."">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.api.investments"/>


    <!--The gateway to be called in parallel-->
    <gateway id="InvestmentGateway" service-interface="com.api.investments.gateways.InvestmentGateway"/>

    <channel id="investmentDetailChannel"/> 
    <service-activator input-channel="investmentDetailChannel" ref="investmentService" method="getAccountPortfolio"/>


    <!--Inbound gateway to invoke Splitter / Aggregator-->
    <gateway id="InvestmentMessageGateway" service-interface="com.api.investments.gateways.InvestmentMessageGateway"
  default-reply-channel="investmentAsyncReceiver" error-channel="investmentAsyncException"/>

    <channel id="investmentAsyncSender"/>
    <channel id="investmentAsyncReceiver"/>

    <!-- Splitter for Invesment Details-->
    <splitter input-channel="investmentAsyncSender" output-channel="investmentSplitChannel" id="investmentDetailsSplitter" ref="investmentComponentsSplitter" />

    <channel id="investmentSplitChannel">
        <queue />
    </channel>

  <!--Calls the Investment Gateway asynchronously using split messages ad send the response in aggregator-->
    <service-activator input-channel="investmentSplitChannel" output-channel="investmentAggregateChannel" ref="investmentAsyncActivator" method="retrieveInvestmentDetailsAsync" requires-reply="true">
        <poller receive-timeout="5000" task-executor="investmentExecutor" fixed-rate="50"/>
    </service-activator>



    <channel id="investmentAsyncException"/>

  <!--Handles failed messages and pass it in aggregator-->
    <transformer input-channel="investmentAsyncException" output-channel="investmentAggregateChannel" ref="invesmentErrorLogger" method="logError"/>

  <!--Aggreggates successfull and failed messaged-->
    <publish-subscribe-channel id="investmentAggregateChannel"/>
    <aggregator input-channel="investmentAggregateChannel" output-channel="investmentAsyncReceiver" id="investmentAggregator"
    ref="investmentComponentsAggregator" correlation-strategy="investmentComponentsCorrelationStrategy"
    expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true" />


    <task:executor id="investmentExecutor" pool-size="10-1000"
                   queue-capacity="5000"/>

</beans:beans>
```

I tried putting my error channel in the poller of the service activator and but the error is still the same but this time it didn't went to the aggregator.
I also tried putting a mid-gateway for the service activator like this
    
but the error became null.

```
<gateway id="InvestmentAsyncActivatorGateway" service-interface="com.api.investments.gateways.InvestmentAsyncActivatorGateway"
default-reply-channel="investmentAggregateChannel" error-channel="investmentAsyncException"/>
```

----UPDATE------

This is the transformer that handles every error message

```
@Component("invesmentErrorLogger")
public class InvesmentErrorLoggerImpl implements InvestmentErrorLogger {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class.getName());

    /**
     * handles all error messages in InvestmentMessageGateway
     * Creates an error message and pass it in the aggregator channel
     * @param invesmentMessageError
     * @return errorMessage
     */
    @Override
    public Message<ErrorDetails> logError(Message<?> invesmentMessageError) {
        if(invesmentMessageError.getPayload().getClass().equals(MessagingException.class)) {
            MessagingException messageException = (MessagingException) invesmentMessageError.getPayload();
            AccountPortfolioRequest failedMsgPayload = (AccountPortfolioRequest) messageException.getFailedMessage().getPayload();
            String logError = "Exception occured in Account Number: " + failedMsgPayload.getiAccNo();
            logger.error(logError);
            ErrorDetails productErrorDetail = new ErrorDetails();
            productErrorDetail.setCode(InvestmentAPIErrorMessages.SVC_ERR_INQACCNTPORTFOLIO);
            productErrorDetail.setMessage(InvestmentAPIErrorMessages.SVC_ERR_INQACCNTPORTFOLIO_DESC + ". Problem occured in Account Number: " + failedMsgPayload.getiAccNo());

            Message<ErrorDetails> errorMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(productErrorDetail)
                    .setHeaderIfAbsent(InvestmentInquiryConstants.INV_CORRELATION_STRATEGY, InvestmentInquiryConstants.INV_CORRELATION_STRATEGY_VALUE)
                    .build();

            return errorMessage;
        }
        else if(invesmentMessageError.getPayload().getClass().equals(MessageDeliveryException.class)) {
            MessageDeliveryException messageException = (MessageDeliveryException) invesmentMessageError.getPayload();
            AccountPortfolioRequest failedMsgPayload = (AccountPortfolioRequest) messageException.getFailedMessage().getPayload();
            String logError = "Exception occured in Account Number: " + failedMsgPayload.getiAccNo();
            logger.error(logError);
            ErrorDetails productErrorDetail = new ErrorDetails();
            productErrorDetail.setCode(InvestmentAPIErrorMessages.SVC_ERR_INQACCNTPORTFOLIO);
            productErrorDetail.setMessage(InvestmentAPIErrorMessages.SVC_ERR_INQACCNTPORTFOLIO_DESC + ". Problem occured in Account Number: " + failedMsgPayload.getiAccNo());

            Message<ErrorDetails> errorMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(productErrorDetail)
                    .setHeaderIfAbsent(InvestmentInquiryConstants.INV_CORRELATION_STRATEGY, InvestmentInquiryConstants.INV_CORRELATION_STRATEGY_VALUE)
                    .build();

            return errorMessage;
        }
        else {
            Exception messageException = (Exception) invesmentMessageError.getPayload();
            String logError = "Exception occured in Investment Gateway ";
            logger.error(logError);
            logger.equals(messageException.getMessage());
            ErrorDetails productErrorDetail = new ErrorDetails();
            productErrorDetail.setCode(InvestmentAPIErrorMessages.SVC_ERR_INQACCNTPORTFOLIO);
            productErrorDetail.setMessage(InvestmentAPIErrorMessages.SVC_ERR_INQACCNTPORTFOLIO_DESC + " " + messageException.getMessage());

            Message<ErrorDetails> errorMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(productErrorDetail)
                    .setHeaderIfAbsent(InvestmentInquiryConstants.INV_CORRELATION_STRATEGY, InvestmentInquiryConstants.INV_CORRELATION_STRATEGY_VALUE)
                    .build();

            return errorMessage;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply.

As the error suggests, you can't send multiple replies (or errors) for a single request; it is strictly one reply per request.

You need another gateway between the splitter and the service.

The mid-flow gateway should have no `service-interface` so it uses the `RequestReplyExchanger`.

Comment: I added a gateway between splitter and aggregator as you suggested without the service interface

         <gateway id="InvestmentAsyncActivatorGateway" default-request-channel="investmentSplitChannel" error-channel="investmentAsyncException"/>

                                                                                                                       But the error doesn't go through the error channel. It exited the service activator right away with the exception I placed.

Comment: Consider to use an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHanderAdvice` for the `<service-activator>`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I tried to put a request-handler-advice-chain inside my service-activator and removed the mid-flow gateway

As what I've seen in other projects, I only set the onFailureExpression, failureChannel, and trapException properties.

I put my updated configuration file in the gist linked below:
https://gist.github.com/floatmawie/7e5ea2ffacdb0b039c8eada374450926

There are three messages I am processing in the splitter-aggregator. I tried putting an exception in one of the messages and the result was successful.

Comment: There were 2 successful and 1 failed message in aggregator as what I am expecting.
But when I am run the request again with the same parameter, I get the error

"No reply produced by handler 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#1', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true."
The succeeding requests will also have the same error.
I have to re-run the application to make it work successfully again

Comment: Also, when I put an error to two or more message request, I get this error and another error in my aggregator,

Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply.